# Error in [.data.table: i has evaluated to type closure. Expecting logical, integer or double. in R

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I've been trying to write a code that optimizes a electricity production facility that must be a web application in R. I'm using shiny package for this issue. At the server part of the code, there must be some calculations made so I've written some equations for this issue. Here's my shinyServer part;

```
function(input, output){
abc <- reactive({
  which(paste(input$tarih, input$zaman, sep = " ") == data$Tarih.ve.Saat)
def <- reactive({
  which(month(input$tarih) == aylıkdata$Ay)
})
})
output$baseload <- renderPrint(
  ((as.numeric(data[abc(),3]) * input$paste("bload", def(), sep =""))  - (input$paste("gaz", def(), sep = "")*input$gazfiyatı) - (input$ürtvergi*input$paste("bload", def(), sep ="")))
)
output$mkud <- renderPrint(
  ((as.numeric(data[abc(),3]) * input$mkudüretim)  - (input$mkudgazkullanımı*input$gazfiyatı) - (input$ürtvergi*input$mkudüretim))
)
output$stup <- renderPrint(
  ((as.numeric(data[abc(),3]) * input$supüretim)  - (input$supgazkullanımı*input$gazfiyatı) - (input$ürtvergi*input$supüretim))
)
output$sdown <- renderPrint(
  ((as.numeric(data[abc(),3]) * input$sdownüretim)  - (input$sdowngazkullanımı*input$gazfiyatı) - (input$ürtvergi*input$sdownüretim))
)
}
)
```

However, when I run the app I get the error:

> Warning: Error in [.data.table: i has evaluated to type closure. Expecting logical, integer or double.

What can be situation there? where is the fault?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at this one as I don't have data to confirm/deny whether this will work... (without spending more time than I would like :p)

My feeling is you can't do `data[abc(),3]` as it doesn't expect a reactive expression within a data.table. I would try to create a reactive data set, and then use this instead. I can't fully interpret your code as you have reactives within reactives... does this work?

This could fail as I don't use shiny that much, but hopefully the idea can be built upon

```
# instead try to return the reactive data object
reactive_data <- reactive({
  con <- which(paste(input$tarih, input$zaman, sep = " ") == data$Tarih.ve.Saat)
  data[con,]
})

#... other things eg the def <- reactive(.. command

# instead, call the reactive data that's the data.table and use [,3] to filter or instead just put [,3] in the output above if nothing else is ever used
output$mkud <- renderPrint(
  ((as.numeric(reactive_data()[,3]) * input$mkudüretim)  - (input$mkudgazkullanımı*input$gazfiyatı) - (input$ürtvergi*input$mkudüretim))
)
```